# Creating object with related objects in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following database tables/EF objects

```
public class Transaction
{
    //some other properties
    public ICollection<TransactionItems> Items {get; set;}

}

public class TransactionItems
{
    //some properties
}
```

What I need to do is, create a new instance of transaction along with several instances of TransactionItems for its Items property and save all of these to my DB

I have tried the following:

```
Transaction trans = new Transaction();
//set its properties
```

Then in a foreach loop I am looping through a collection and creating a new TransactionItem for each member and attempting to add it to the trans object Item Collection

```
foreach(var item in myCollection)
{

     TransactionItem newItem = new TransactionItem();
     //set its properties

     //add it to the tran Item collection
    tran.TransactionItems.Add(newItem);//getting null reference here...

}
```

I am getting a null reference exception when I attempt to add a transactionITem to the Item collection of my Transaction object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the property to hold a collection instance in the constructor:

```
Items = new HashSet<TransactionItems>();
```

Comment: If you define it this way be careful that your `Equals` and `GetHashCode` operators specifically take the primary keys/unique constraint properties into consideration, and not other properties.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Or just use reference equality.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever Initialize `TransactionItems` in the constructor for `Transaction` or in your actual code?

```
public class Transaction
{
    public Transaction()
    {
        Items = new List<TransactionItems>();
    }

    //some other properties
    public ICollection<TransactionItems> Items {get; set;}
}
```

Or less preferrably (unless you also do the above):

```
Transaction trans = new Transaction()
{
    Items = myCollection.Select(
        item => new TransactionItem
        {
            // set its properties
        })
        .ToList();
};
```